# Optimisation of backsolve base function

Tags: r, optimization, linear-algebra, rcpp

I am wondering if there could be any possible was to optimize the base package function backsolve ? for example using Rccp. I have googled a bit but couldn't find any response:

1. is there an alternative package doing better ?
2. if no is it worth striving to do it by myself ? because maybe the base function is already well optimised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of these function dispatch pretty directly to compiled code, often C or sometimes Fortran.  Do some analysis and take some closer looks before diving into this, it is not clear you will gain anything. Here it even says under *Details:* in the help page:

> This is a wrapper for the level-3 BLAS routine ‘dtrsm’.

So it is unlikely you will do better, unless you are a real numerical analysis expert.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Well I guess I have to improve other part of my code